# How do I change the color of an ArcGISImageServiceLayer?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geoprocessing-service, image-service

I have published an image service of a raster layer (.tif).
When I use it online, it is grayscale. 
In ArcMap, I have the option to change the color of the display.
How can I do this from the webservice (either when publishing, or consuming)?

Here is the code I use to consume the service.

```
var params = new esri.layers.ImageServiceParameters();
    params.noData = 0;

var montgomeryCountyLayer = new    esri.layers.ArcGISImageServiceLayer(".../arcgis/rest/services/Montgomery_Layer/ImageServer", {
      imageServiceParameters: params,
      opacity: .5,
      id: "montgomeryCounty"
    });

    map.addLayer(montgomeryCountyLayer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is you can't...
ESRI designed the image services as products for analysis. The default is greyscale, which you can bring the product into ArcMap and color ramp under symbology as usual. However we tend to want the user to not take that extra step and be able to load the image already symbolized to its appropriate color.  Well we can symbolize it ourselves in ArcMap and save the symbology as a raster function template.  Upon sharing the product as an image service, we can apply the raster function template and set it as default...
This is great, however it converts the image to RGB, therefore upon indentifying the feature, we can see the RGB values rather than the raw pixel value.  If this is okay fro your output, then there is your answer.  However, I needed users to be able to view raw pixel values.  There is a checkbox under symbology to display raw pixel values when using indentify tool... this however is another step for the user to take and "understand" more so... So there is no real way to color ramp your image service for your user to open and view analytically AND cartographically without taking a few steps for themselves...

Let me know if you need screenshots, I'd be glad to help you out further if need be...

Hope this was your "best" answer!